# How to overried Backdrop.js in Component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i want to override Backrdrop.js file in my componenet

File path : react\node_modules\@material-ui\core\Backdrop\Backdrop.js

default style :

```
var styles = {
   root: {
   zIndex: -1,
   position: 'fixed',
   right: 0,
   bottom: 0,
   top: 0,
```

nd I want to set top value 0 to 58 or other value. How to do override in component.

Comment: What's wrong with `styles.top = 58` ?

Comment: I don't want to chnage in core file, I want ot overired in my component that value